# special character vertical bar(|) automatically changes to HEX code in php?

Tags: php, special-characters, domdocument

I've used php domDocument for parsing HTML content and appended text to the url of the image tag and saved it as HTML.

My PHP code is as follows:

```
$dom = new domDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTMLFile('test.html');
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach($images as $img)
{
    $url = $img->getAttribute('src');   
    $alt = $img->getAttribute('alt');
    echo $src = 'http://api.imgble.com/resize|0.5|0.5/'.$url;
    $img->setAttribute( 'src' , $src);
}
$str=$dom->saveHTML();
print $str;
```

The problem is when I print the url(`$src`) before saving, it shows the special character exactly as it displayed.

```
http://api.imgble.com/resize|0.5|0.5|0/http://farm1.static.flickr.com/57/197881059_aeb724b1cf.jpg
```

But when I saved & printed it, it shows HEX code of that special character i.e., %7C for that vertical bar **|** as follows:

```
http://api.imgble.com/resize%7C0.5%7C0.5%7C0/http://farm1.static.flickr.com/57/197881059_aeb724b1cf.jpg
```

I even used number code of that special character and even decoded it using `html_entity_decode()`. But nothing works. Does anybody came across this problem?

Comment: See `urlencode`. There are [many "special" characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) which can't appear in a URL.

Comment: could it be that you're opening the url in the browser, and it's the browser that's doing the conversion, not PHP?

Comment: It's perfectly correct for the character to be escaped. - [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: These are not htmlentities. htmlenties look like: `#&1234;`. This is URL encoding which looks like: `%1A`.